# How to override JavaScript alert function inside an iframe before it finished loading?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, overriding

I am using **headless chrome browser** with wraith(https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith). The **problem** is when I have a page that opens an **alert** wraith fails

```
ERROR: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Bla bla bla.}
  (Session info: headless chrome=71.0.3578.98)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=71.0.3578.33 (269aa0e3f0db08097f0fe231c7e6be200b6939f7),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64)
```

This is what I tried, but has failed so far:

```
const BACKEND_USERNAME = "";
const BACKEND_PASSWORD = "";

function resizeIFrameToFitContent(iFrame) {
    iFrame.width = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}


var original_url_asked = document.referrer;
if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {//maybe 500 or 404 page
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //we ended up on login page, let's login
        $('body > div:nth-child(23) > div.backend_right_content > div > div > form > input[type="password"]:nth-child(3)').prop('value', BACKEND_PASSWORD);
        $('body > div:nth-child(23) > div.backend_right_content > div > div > form > input[type="text"]:nth-child(1)').prop('value', BACKEND_USERNAME);
        $('body > div:nth-child(23) > div.backend_right_content > div > div > form > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(5)').click();//submit form

        //we are logged in
        $('body').empty();//clear all the stuff
        //since we can't redirect, we'll open a full page iframe with the url we wanted to see initially
        $('body').append('<iframe id="ifr" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="" ></iframe>');

        //load the original_url finally
        $("#ifr").attr("src", original_url_asked);//cannot redirect or wraith complains


        //hide the menu and other elements, for smaller screenshots
        $('#ifr').on('load', function () {
            $('#ifr').contents().find('div.backend_left, div.backend_right_top').remove();
            resizeIFrameToFitContent(document.getElementById('ifr'));
        });
    });
}

//important or wraith will not understand it is ready to take a screenshot
var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
setTimeout(callback, 20000);//wait for page to load
```

Comment: What do you mean by it has failed so far? Any errors?

Comment: @TomM well I suppose he still have the same error generated by wraith, thus his failed attempt ... :-)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy yeah that makes sense.

Comment: did you try setting `iframe.contentWindow.alert` and `iframe.contentWindow.prototype.alert`  BEFORE setting the 'src' attribute?

Comment: and are you sure it is an `alert` and not a `confirm`?

Comment: yes i'm sure it is an alert, iframe.contentWindow.... gives ERROR: javascript error: Cannot set property 'alert' of undefined

Comment: @max4ever, How important is it to run using headless chrome? It looks like as it currently is, wraith using CasperJS/PhantomJS has finer control over handling JavaScript and the browser.

Comment: Steve, when having many urls to check wraith seems to hang with casperjs, the github solution is to use Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot prevent alert window using JavaScript, as by the time `wraith` executes the `before_capture` script the alert popup is already there. So as `wraith` tries to execute JavaScript leaving the alert popup open, webdriver raises the error you are encountering.

You can switch to `phantomjs` to resolve the issue, but if you want to stick to selenium headless chrome and `wraith`, you have to patch `wraith` to handle the modal popups properly.

> **File**: {Ruby Installation Dir}\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\wraith-4.2.3\lib\wraith\save_images.rb
>   **Line**: 129

```
driver.navigate.to url
# patch to handle rogue alert popups at page load
while true
  begin
    driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss
  rescue
    break
  end
end
# patch end
driver.execute_async_script(File.read(global_before_capture)) if global_before_capture
```

The while loop will dismiss as many alert popups it finds when the page navigates to your URL, and then run the `before_capture` script.

Comment: phantomJs and similar don't work, see https://github.com/BBC-News/wraith/issues/508#issuecomment-351072629 , i tried your code but the problem is that I first login then after redirect I open the intended page, so the patch maybe it works, but not in my case :/

Comment: How do you login? using the `before_capture` script? can you provide code samples of the process?

Comment: yes using the before_capture script, please see my question, I've updated the js code, thank you

Comment: In that case just add `sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts"` attribute to your `iframe`. Unless you add `allow-modals` to it all alert calls will be ignored. you can still dump the alert calls to console.

Comment: perfect, i'll have to google it up why this works :D, it works without the patch

Comment: You can see other sandbox options [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) if you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an access to a cross-origin `iframe` then you can override native `alert` function like follows:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="about:blank"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframe = document.getElementById('ifr');

iframe.addEventListener('load', function(event)
{
    iframe.contentWindow.alert = function(s){console.log(s)};
});

iframe.src = 'iframe.html';
</script>
```

**Code from `iframe.html`**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert('iframe'); // this will always native function and you can not override it
</script>

<!-- BUT the following message you will get in console: -->
<input type="button" value="try it" onclick="alert('Your native alert was overriden!')">
```

Now you can click on the button in this iframe and you will get the message `'Your native alert was overriden!'` in your console.

In other words: you can override native `alert` function, but you have not the possibility to override it before the iframe `window` was loaded. We have not some event for this case. Only after iframe `window` was loaded you can use your overriden function. If it is enough for you then you can use it.

But something more you can not do.

**What is important to understand:**

Always after setting from new `src` for your iframe the iframe will load original (native) `alert` function. And because of this you have to override it always after new site in your iframe was loaded.

### Alternative solution

Thanks the hint from user Munim Munna in the comment we have a perfect solution:
You can add **[`sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox)** as attribute to your `iframe` like follows:

```
<iframe id="ifr" src="about:blank" sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

and all alert boxes will be ignored unless you add `allow-modals` to this list. In the console in this case you will get an error-message:

> Ignored call to `'alert()'`. The document is sandboxed, and the 'allow-modals' keyword is not set.

And if someone does not like it, than he can override the `alert` function like in the first part from this my answer.